# What is inconsistency in the printing of this question which lead for BONUS?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

> Following is the question from IIT-JEE 2017 held on May 21. This question, as you can see is declared to be bonus due to inconsistency in printing of question.

[image]

> (This is multiple correct answer type question, i.e. one or more than one answers may be correct)
>
> And this is what is written in the official answer key :

[image]

> But I am not able to understand what's the problem here? As you can see in the following [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%3D(x)(cos(pi(x%2Bfloor(x))))) (link to Alpha, and image from Desmos)

[image]

> The graph is disocontinuous at every integer except $x=0$. Hence, correct answer must be options $\mathrm{(A)(C)(D)}$.
>
> This is the the screenshot of full page, in case you need to verify.

[image]

> **Can someone explain why is this question declared to be bonus?**

Thanks!

Comment: There's no issue with your answer. "Inconsistency in the printing" suggests some exam papers may have had different wording of the problem, or different choices (hence they couldn't autograde the answer sheets). Rather than count it as zero, they chose to count it as $+4$ for everybody (regardless of contestant's answer, i.e., a bonus).

Comment: @quasi Probably you are correct, I didn't think about this possibility. Let me confirm from my teachers and my friends. If the reason for bonus is what you have written in your comment, I'll close my question.